# What are some good non-English phrases with singular and plural forms that can be used to test an internationalization and localization library?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, internationalization, string-formatting

I've been working on a .NET library to assist with internationalization of an application.  It's written in C#, called **[SmartFormat](http://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat)**, and is open-source on GitHub.

It contains [Grammatical Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number) rules for multiple languages that determine the correct singular/plural form based on the template and locale. The rules were obtained from [Unicode Language Plural Rules](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html).

When translating a phrase that has words that depend on a quantity (such as nouns, verbs, and adjectives), you specify the multiple forms and the formatter chooses the correct form based on these rules.

An example in English: (notice the syntax is nearly identical to `String.Format`)

```
var message = "There {0:is:are} {0} {0:item:items} remaining.";
var output = Smart.Format(culture, message, items.Count);
```

I would like to write unit tests for many of the supported languages.  However, I only speak English and Spanish (which both have the same grammatical-number rules).

**What are some good non-English test phrases that can be used for these unit tests?**
I am looking for phrases similar to `"There {0:is:are} {0} {0:item:items} remaining."`. Notice how this example requires a specific verb and noun based on the quantity.

**A note about syntax**:

This library looks for `:` delimited words and chooses the correct word based on the rules defined for the locale.  For example, in Polish, there are 3 plural forms for the word "File" : 1 "plik", 2-4 "pliki", 5-21 "plików".  So, you would specify all 3 forms in the format string: `"{0} {0:plik:pliki:plików}"`.

The words are typically ordered from smallest possible value to largest, such as `"{0:zero:one:two:few:many:other}"`, as defined by the [Unicode Language Plural Rules](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html).

Additional information about this code has been discussed here: [Localization of singular/plural words - what are the different language rules for grammatical numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136627/localization-of-singular-plural-words-what-are-the-different-language-rules-for)

Comment: This library is pure C#, and I'm pretty sure that `System.String` is fully compatible with Unicode.  I haven't explicitly tested it, but there should be no problems with Unicode.  [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144397/what-are-the-best-practices-for-handling-unicode-strings-in-c) talks a little about Unicode and C#.

Comment: In fact, I would love a "test phrase" in Unicode!

Comment: @Scott: Could you please explain the "words should always be specified in smallest-to-largest order" principle. For example, in Russian for the word "File" we have: 0 "файлов", 1 "файл", 2-4 "файла", 5-20 "файлов" (as with 0), 21,31,41,... "файл" (as with 1) etc. Given this, what format should I use for this word? If I specify "{0:файлов:файл:файла}" and the number of files is 2, then the correct form is no. 3 "файла", but if we have 11 files then the correct form is no. 1 "файлов" even though 11 > 2. And for 21 files the correct form is no. 2 "файл" despite that 21 > 11 > 2.

Comment: Does this system handle 0 values (or less than 0)?

Comment: @Igor Korkhov: I modified that section to better describe the order, and I added a link to the [Unicode Language Plural Rules](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html). Since 21,31,41 fall into the "one" rule, it comes before 2-4.

Comment: @Hans Kesting: Great question. In English, sometimes "zero" falls into the "many" category, and sometimes it needs its own definition. So, in the current English rules, the system looks at the number of words supplied.  If 2 words are supplied, they are "one:many"; if 3 are supplied, they are "zero:one:many", and if 4 are supplied, "negative:zero:one:many".  
For example: `"You have {0:no|one|several} {0:email|emails}"`.  Cool huh?

Comment: Does your system support ordinal numbers?

Comment: @Random832: Yes it does! But this is actually a separate feature. The system has a set of "extensions", and one of the extensions currently in development is an English "numbers to words" function that works like this: `"{0:NumberWords} is {0:ordinal}"` => `"One is first", "Two is second", "Three is third", "Twenty One is Twenty First" etc..`

Comment: Note that there is data in the unicode CLDR for numbers to words, you should use this rather than just developing an english only feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to contribute with the approximate Turkish translation of your sample phrase, so you can test for the case where number of possible forms equals 1. ;)

`{0} nesne kaldı.` = *`({0} items remaining.)`*

Although Turkish words are pluralized regularly with suffixes, the plural forms are never used when the number of items are specified. So the above should be rendered the same in each case:

`1 nesne kaldı.`

`2 nesne kaldı.`

`42 nesne kaldı.`

However, when the count is not explicitly specified, it may become grammatically important to indicate if we are talking about one or more items. So the message "`Do you want to delete the selected item(s)?`" should be rendered like this:

`Seçili nesneyi silmek istiyor musunuz?` (when item count=1)

`Seçili nesneleri silmek istiyor musunuz?` (when item count>1)

So I guess the format for this would be:

`Seçili {0:nesneyi:nesneleri} silmek istiyor musunuz?`

Comment: Awesome!  That is an excellent example!  
Thank you for explaining how non-explicit quantities require pluralization ... I haven't heard of that before, and so I wasn't planning on unit-testing Turkish because I thought it always had 1 form.
But I will definitely include these phrases in my tests!

Comment: OK, I added your example to my unit tests. The code is pretty self explanatory. If you're interested, take a look (look for `Test_Turkish`) [PluralLocalizationExtensionTests.cs](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat/blob/LocalizationPlugin/src/SmartFormat.Tests/PluralLocalizationExtensionTests.cs)